# How to get selected column-names of Datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

i have found several examples/questions about getting row numbers of the selected cells but not many about getting Column names.

i want to check if a column is named: Frequency. i check if the user select 2 rows bofore doing my stuff.

i tried the following approaches:

```
if (Dat.SelectedColumns[0].ToString() == "Frequency"
    || Dat.SelectedColumns[1].ToString() == "Frequency")
```

this was not working, my initially thought was that i needed the headernames to check, my next try:

```
if (Dat.SelectedColumns[0].HeaderText == "Frequency"
   || Dat.SelectedColumns[1].HeaderText == "Frequency")
```

this is not working, as selectedColumns remains null. (inex out of range exception)

is there a way to get the names of the selected columns/check if the name is "frequency"?

edit:

```
// get the Column name of the selected data
int Xcor = Dat.CurrentCellAddress.X;
string ColumnName = Dat.Columns[Xcor].Name;
```

this method is not working im my case, i need to get 2 ColumnNames, not only the current selected

Comment: r u selecting two columns at a time or do  you want to get the selcted column name and the column name next to selected column .... ......

Comment: yes i am (click and drag in the datagridview)

Comment: What is the row selection mode for your grid ?

Comment: i have multi-select = true and readonly = true , all others default

Comment: "The SelectionMode property must be set to DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullColumnSelect or DataGridViewSelectionMode.ColumnHeaderSelect for the SelectedColumns property to be populated with selected columns." -- MSDN

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure of the `SelectionMode` which you have set for the grid, since you need to look out for specific columns it would be better to go for `CellSelect`.

In that case you have `dataGridView1.SelectedCells` and by going through each you would have the RowIndex as well as the ColumnIndex which would help you identify the specific column.

If this is not what you intend please update the question.

Comment: thank you, that is a way to get the results i want, just check all cells. But isnt there a faster way?

Comment: I don't know but please do update this if you come across one